# prependTo() quote to parent P

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I had to make a quick page with "articles" from some employees, real simple, just 3 blog posts with about 500 words each. My boss wanted me to make it so that we could highlight some parts of the text from each article as a blockquote that would stay within the text, either floating to the left or the right (example: https://www.digitaldesignjournal.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/free-blockquote-design-templates13.png).
I've never really used JS/JQ before, so i tried looking at a few tutorials online and the below is what I've got. However, as I said, I wish to "clone" and place a part of a paragraph to its parent P to be displayed as a quote but I cannot seem to get it to work, as the part I'd want to highlight as a quote either does not appear at all, or it appears the wrong place.
 If i just say prependTo('p') the quote would obviously appear at every P, so if there is a say to only have it appear at the parent P, that would be ideal.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
      var $quote = $(this).parent('p');
      $('span.blockquote').clone().prependTo($quote).addClass('quote');
      });
```

```css
   .quote {
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-style: italic;
    color: red;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    max-width: 9.5em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    }
```

```html
 
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>

    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, <span class="blockquote">quis nostrud exercitation</span> ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
    
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I am not sure what i am doing wrong, but then again I am very new to this. If anyone has a solution i would greatly appreciate it.

**edit: sorry if this is still unclear.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to include specific details of the error you are having. Saying you "*can't get it to work*" is not a clear indication of what the problem is. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and this [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to see what to include in your question so we have the information required to help.

Comment: `this` within the ready function is the `document`

Comment: @FluffyKitten I apologize that my question was unclear. I've tried to update it, and hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? Parent selector traverses the DOM upwards.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $quote = $('span.blockquote');
  $quote.clone().prependTo($quote.parent()).addClass('quote');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you GitGitBoom for your answer! However when i tried this, it places the quote at first P instead of at the P the <span class="blockquote"> is in. Is there any way to fix that? As there are several parts of different texts that needs to be "quoted". Sorry if i am not explaining myself very well.

Comment: Just changed it to prependTo your blockquote's parent. I think that's what your looking for.

Comment: Thank you! Getting closer! However, if i have two quotes, lets say on in the 3rd <p> and one in the 7th <p>, then both quotes appear in each <p>, is there a way to make it so the quoted part isn't repeated when you have more than one quote?

Comment: You'll have to make the blockquote selector more specific. There a multiple ways to do this. The easiest being to add ids to your block quote elements and selecting  each via ```$('#blockquote-id')```. What is the context here, are you prepending the quotes on P hover or click?